# Pitch correction using Fast Foruier Transform

Tags: matlab, fft, audio, ifft, pitch

I am very new to digital signal processing and I have a project about audio programming. For the project, I wanted to try to make an Auto-tune like effect.
I started by experimenting on the signal processing on Matlab.

Firstly, I started by trying to change the frequency of a given audio signal. To do so, I had in mind to just take the fft of the signal windows, shift the frequency samples accordingly (of course taking into conisderation that the frequency samples are mirrored on the fft result) and to take the ifft but it does not seem to work.

Is my reasoning for pitch shifting conceptually correct and I am just making a simple mistake or should I do it in a different way?

Thank you

Comment: Pitch shifting is well explored technical area. What research have you done on pitch shifting ? What have you learned and what do you have problems with?

Comment: Look up “phase vocoder” for more info on doing this; it will increase the pitch while maintain the speed or vice versa

Comment: why do this in the frequency domain ?? I wrote it in time domain, PSOLA / keith Lent algorithm is freaking awesome, OK the implementation may not be that simple, but it's worth ...although doing this in the frequency domain is as complex as in the time domain [My Lent Code in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ns5K1FHtd4)

Comment: Thanks for all the replies people. And yes I guess I just didn't know the term "phase vocoder", now that I look that up, I can find a lot of resources. So thanks @DanBoschen !

Comment: In my uni courses, I mainly learned about dsp techniques in the frequency domain, i guess that's why i thought it would be just too complex to do it in the time domain. I'll look those algorithms up as well, thanks @ederwander